# How you parse a collection of email addresses with mimekit?

Tags: c#, mimekit

With .NET's `MailAddressCollection` you call `.Add(addresses)` where addresses is a comma separated list of email addresses. Does Mimekit has an equivalent?

I don't want to just call `String.Split` because that doesn't take into account commas inside quoted names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Mimekit, the easiest way is to use the static method `InternetAddressList.Parse`. Despite the name, this does handle email addresses.

Comment: Yep! This is the correct method to use. The TryParse methods can also be used if you don’t want to deal with exceptions.